# Remove a entire column in file A which contain the names of fileds in file B

Tags: awk

I have a file with 500 columns. I need to remove some columns, which the names are described in a list in another file. For example

`fileA`:

```
    id1 id22 id43 id4 id5 id6 id7 id68 id9 id10 id11 
    TT AA AG TC TT AA AG TC DD AA CC     
    TT AC GG TC TT AG AG TC AD AA DC
```

`fileB`:

```
    id1
    id5
    id10
    id68
```

Desired Output:

```
         id22 id43 id4 id6 id7 id9 id11 
           AA AG TC AA AG DD CC     
           AC GG TC AG AG AD DC
```

Comment: To delete column see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551219/deleting-columns-from-a-file-with-awk-or-from-command-line-on-linux or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361632/delete-a-column-with-awk-or-sed
Now only the part with finding out the column is missing, probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578358/how-to-find-the-column-number-in-a-text-file-using-unix-commands might be helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to call this a one liner but you could do it on the fly with very basic tools:

```
cut -d' ' -f $(head -n 1 fileA | tr -s ' ' '\n' | cat -n | grep -wvf fileB | cut -f 1 | tr '\n ' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//' -e 's/^,//') fileA
```

Explanation:

The `cut` command `cut -d' ' -f [...] fileA` is simply using space as a delimiter `-d' '`, and selecting which fields `-f` to leave. It is then a question of which fields/columns to use, which are given by a comma-separated index list we create on the fly:

`head -n 1 fileA` selects the header line only, `tr -s ' ' '\n'` changes all spaces to newlines (and `-s`queezes multiple occurrences into single ones), `cat -n` adds line numbers to this list.

These line numbers are identical to the original column numbers, thus we need to pick the remaining ones. With `grep -wvf fileB` we do an inverse `grep`ping with the headers from the deletion list (use `-w` to make sure that e.g. `id1` does not also delete `id11`), then `cut -f 1` this list to the line numbers only, and translate newlines into commas (`tr '\n' ','`), giving us our comma-separated list of remain columns. However in the last step, there are still commas before and after the list, so we need to delete them with `sed -e 's/,$//' -e 's/^,//'`. So now the outer `cut`'s field list is complete.

Maybe run the inner pipes separately as counter check first - the excess column index does not influence the result.